# Separate jQuery for Individual Comments?

Tags: plugins, comments, jquery

So far I have designed this function to display rating stars on the front end below every comment:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'additional_fields' );    
function additional_fields ($below) {
  global $comment;    
if(!get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'rating', true ) ) {      
$ratsec = '<form action="'.get_permalink().'" method="get" class="comment-form-rating">';    
$ratsec .= '<div id="stars1">
<div class="option starr1">1</div>
<div class="option starr2">2</div>
<div class="option starr3">3</div>
<div class="option starr4">4</div>
<div class="option starr5">5</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>';    
    $ratsec .= '<input type="hidden" name="p" value="'.get_the_ID().'"/>';
    $ratsec .= '<input type="text" value="" name="rating['.$comment->comment_ID.']" id="rate22" class="fruit-name"/>';    
    $ratsec .= '<label for="rating">'. __('Rating') . '</label>';    
  $ratsec .= '<input type="submit" value="submit" />';
  $ratsec .= '</form>';
  $below = $below .$ratsec;
  return $below;
}
else
$ratsec = "";
$below = $below .$ratsec;
  return $below;
}
```

and use this jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var $option = $('.option');
    var $fruit = $('.fruit-name');
    var $last;
    $option.click(function() {
    $fruit.val(this.innerHTML)
    })
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Now when I am adding a hovering action in it to make star yellow it is yellowing all the star's of all the comments plus when I am click on any star its value is updated to all the fields below comment.

What I want here is make it work individually for every comment? like if I press 2 star for comment id 33 it should only change the color and the value of comment id 33 field. not all the comments.

Comment: jQuery question. Voting as off topic.

Comment: I cant see your code ? please write it in code format ? and its not off topic ? it include wordpress comment system - I am attaching jquerry in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your jquery with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){

   $(document).ready(function() {
    var $option = $('.option');
    var $fruit = $('.fruit-name');
    var $last;
    var parent
    $option.click(function() {
        parent=$(this).parents('.comment-form-rating');
        $('.fruit-name',parent).val(this.innerHTML)
    })
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

your script not working because `.fruit-name` not contain correct reference variable.

---

**Updated**

for debugging put code and check.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){

       $(document).ready(function() {
        var $option = $('.option');
        var $fruit = $('.fruit-name');
        var $last;
        var parent
        $option.click(function() {
         parent1=$(this).parents('.comment-form-rating');
         parent2=$('.option').parents('.comment-form-rating');
         console.log(parent1);
         console.log(parent2);
         $('.fruit-name',parent1).val(this.innerHTML)
        })
    });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

in above code,after click any `.option` class parent1 contain only one value because it is referenced(so only change to one `.fruit-name` class).but parent2 contain as many as your comment(so change to all `.fruit-name` class)

Comment: Great - working now - But can you please explain it in a little details in case I need this in future.

Comment: In your code.you give click event to all .option class,when .option click you change value of .fruit-name but which so change occurs on all .fruit-name class.but in my code  basically i detect parent class of currently click .option class which is .comment-form-rating.and change value of .fruit-name class which lies in current .comment-form-rating class.so change takes place only for one .fruit-name class.sorry for my bad english is it understandable?

Comment: yes its totally understand able but what I am confused in is - all the comments have same .comment-form-rating class - like all the stars have .option class ? then why now its working ?

Comment: see updated part in my answer.is it cool?

Comment: please update answer with both of your answer that was working and I haven't check this but this is more awsum than the code you type before wow you are a genius dear.

Comment: check i updated my answer.